# Making AOSP's libcore module recognize custom library code

Tags: android, makefile, android-source

I have a custom Java library that I want to utilize in the `libcore/luni` module. I added my library's Java source code and custom makefile in `external` and the contents of the `out` seem to indicate that the build process recognized my library and compiled the source code accordingly.

What steps do I need to take so that I can use my library code within the source code of`libcore/luni`. For example, what additions do I need to make to `libcore/luni`'s makefiles?